# Unable to add button element in the DOM for youtube using an chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am trying to build a Hobby Chrome Extension. So What I am trying to do is give some control buttons for youtube video. My Manifest.json is

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage", "webNavigation"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js", "insertPlayerButtons.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["insertPlayerButtons.js"],
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/"],
        "css" : ["insertPlayerButton.css"]
    }],
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

My ContentScript is

```
var currentspeed = 1; 
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      addElement();
    }
  }

function addElement () {
    var container = document.getElementById('player-container');
    var testButton = document.createElement("button");
    testButton.type = "button";
    testButton.onclick = test;
    var forwardText = document.createTextNode("test"); 
    forwardButton.appendChild(forwardText);
    container.appendChild(forwardButton);
};
function test() {
    //dosomething
};
```

My background.js is

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function() {
    addElement();
  });
```

So what is happening is when we I load youtube home page i.e `youtube.com` then there is no `player-container` div so no element gets added to dom.

After that when I click on some video and go to video page `https://www.youtube.com/watch?****` page the scripts run again but somehow I don't able to access dom. Even though onHistoryStateUpdated event is fired by background.js. But I am not able to append Childs in Dom because `container` is coming as null.

If I just reload `https://www.youtube.com/watch?****` this page then everything works fine.

Only when I move from `youtube.com` to `https://www.youtube.com/watch?****` it stops working.

This is first extension I am trying to build so if I am missing something basic.... please excuse

Comment: [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: Using given method when I navigate from youtube home to video first time element is not getting added. when I move again from home to video it is getting added. I found out that event is getting fired before new page is loaded .. so I am getting document of old page ... so when I move from home to video ... I am getting home doc so container is null.. when I move from video to home I am getting video doc and elements getting added ... so when I move again from home to video element is shown

Comment: That answer describes how to see all events: for your case 'yt-navigation-finish' is better.

Comment: I tried both the events but somehow both the events were getting fired even before video page is loaded ... Now I am using settimeout on 'yt-navigation-finish' event.... Not good but it is working ... I will remain this question open for now.. Thanks @wOxxOm

Comment: Timeout is a viable option. A more exact one is MutationObserver on a parent/ancestor element that already exists at yt-navigation-finish.